# hashHistory not working

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have React Project and the react-router structure is as follows

```
var routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute component={ Greeting }/>
      <Route path="user/:user_id" component={ Profile }>
      </Route>
      <Route path="playlists" component={PlaylistIndex}/>
      <Route path="playlists/:playlist_id" component={SinglePlaylist}/>
      <Route path="songs" component={SongIndex}/>
      <Route path="songs/:song_id" component={SingleSong}/>
    </Route>
);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var container = document.getElementById("root");
  Modal.setAppElement(container);
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>{routes}</Router>,
    container
  );
});
```

However if I try to refresh or go to a page using a path it should have IE *localhost:3000/user/1* it does not load the component it should. It worked fine with an older version of react-router when it had a  default history prop built in, but now that react-router has gone through some updates I am required to use hashHistory as a prop, but it does not seem to work the same. Any help would be phenomenal!

Comment: If you have server side rendering up, and does routing matching on the server side. hashHistory will not work, you will have to use browserHistory. Check https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory

Comment: Any particular reason why you would want to use hashHistory and not browserHistory?

Comment: I think it was functioning on hashHistory before and I figured it would be a quick fix @ElodSzopos

Comment: @ElodSzopos plus browserHistory is doing something funny to my ajax request as well as my <Link to={etc etc} /> something on why refresh isn't working or why the hash isn't being added to the end of the query string would be amazing

Answer (score 1):

Hash history uses a #. It should look like this: localhost/#/user/1